# Como fazer o contador funcionar para permitir três tentativas?

Tags: javascript

A questão é a seguinte:
"Altere o código anterior para que o usuário tenha 3 tentativas para realizar o login." O código que veio da Alura é o seguinte:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>

    var loginCadastrado = "alura";
    var senhaCadastrada = "alura321";

    var loginInformado = prompt("Informe seu login");
    var senhaInformada = prompt("Informe sua senha");

    if( loginCadastrado == loginInformado && senhaCadastrada == senhaInformada ) {

        alert("Bem-vindo ao sistema " + loginInformado);
    } else {

        alert("Login inválido. Tente novamente");
    }
</script>
```

O código que eu fiz é esse :

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>

    var login_cadastrado = "alura";
    var senha_cadastrada = "alura123";

    var login_informado = prompt("Informe o login cadastrado");
    var senha_informada = prompt("Informe sua senha");

    var contador = 1;

    while(contador <= 3){
    if(login_cadastrado == login_informado && senha_cadastrada == senha_informada){
        alert("Bem vindo ao sistema " + login_informado);
        break;
    }
    contador = contador + 1;
    else{
        alert("usuário ou senha incorreto");

        
    }


    </script>
```

Fiz uma outra versão com o contador abaixo do else mas esse entra em looping infinito, não aumenta o contador e não sei resolver.

Estou uns 4 dias tentando resolver e não consigo, também não quero olhar o código do professor antes de aprender efetivamente a fazer o código.

Comment: Coloca pelo menos o seu HTML tb na pergunta, vai ajudar para alguém te responder

Answer (score 0):

Para perguntar o login 3x você também precisa colocar os "**prompt**" dentro do laço de repetição.

Para incrementar o contador você pode usar diretamente o operador "**++**". Esse operador, quando usado antes da variável ele primeiro incrementa e depois compara a condição. Quando usado depois ele faz o contrário, primeiro compara a condição e depois incrementa.

Nesse exemplo usando o "**do while**" primeiro executamos o código e depois fazemos a comparação da condição para realizar o loop.

```
var login_cadastrado = "alura";
var senha_cadastrada = "alura123";
var contador = 0;

do {
    var login_informado = prompt("Informe o login cadastrado");
    var senha_informada = prompt("Informe sua senha");

    if (login_cadastrado == login_informado && senha_cadastrada == senha_informada){
        alert("Bem vindo ao sistema " + login_informado);
        break;
    } else {
        alert("usuário ou senha incorreto");
    }
} while (++contador < 3);
```

Recomendo que você pratique a lógica alterando esse script e também tentando usar outros tipos de laços de repetição. Ademais, bons estudos.

Answer (score 0):

Você está adicionando mais números ao seu contador, ou seja, a cada volta o seu contador recebe mais um número, por conta do sinal de "+" nessa parte:

```
contador = contador + 1;
```

Isso está criando um loop infinito.
Tente fazer algo nesse modelo:

```
var login_cadastrado = "alura";
var senha_cadastrada = "alura123";

var login_informado = prompt("Informe o login cadastrado");
var senha_informada = prompt("Informe sua senha");

var contador = 3;

while(contador <= 3){
    contador = contador - 1;
    if(contador = 0){
        alert("Desculpe, você atingiu o limite de tentativas.")
    }else{
        if(login_cadastrado == login_informado && senha_cadastrada == senha_informada){
            alert("Bem vindo ao sistema " + login_informado);
        break;
        }
        else{
            alert("Usuário ou senha incorreto. Você tem mais " + contador + "tentativas.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Caso não dê certo, me avise, não tive como testar pois não tinha o resto do código.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var login_cadastrado = "alura";
var senha_cadastrada = "alura123";

function login(n) {
  for (var tentativa = 0; tentativa < n; ++tentativa) {
    var login_informado = prompt("Informe o login cadastrado");
    var senha_informada = prompt("Informe sua senha");

    if(login_cadastrado == login_informado && senha_cadastrada == senha_informada) {
      alert("Bem vindo ao sistema " + login_informado);
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("usuário ou senha incorreto");
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

login(3);
```